# Render ASP.NET MVC partial view based on a condition on client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In our ASP.NET MVC 4 app, we have four partial views: View1, View2, View3, View4. When user selects a number, say, 2, from a dropdown and click on a submit button we want to render only partial views View2. Likewise, when 3 is selected we want to render View3 and so on. I tried the following but it does not render View2. I assume we cannot do this from inside script tag.

```
<div id="v2">
    <script>
        if (n==2) {
            @{Html.RenderPartial("View2");}
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

How can we achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load it asynchronously using jQuery `load` method on the click event of the button. Something like this.

```
$(function(){

  $(document).on("click","#btnItem1",function() {
     var val=$("#YourDropDownID").val();     
     if(val==2)
     {
        $("#DivContainerForCustForm").load("@Url.Action("CustomerForm","Home")");
     }
  });  

});
```

Assuming you have the `CustomerForm` action method in `HomeController` returns the relevant html markup you need.This action could return a partial view.

You may update your jQuery selectors & HTML markup to make it more generic to work with more than one control/div's.

Comment: Thanks to @Shyju for his help.